# Resolve User Name from Email Address

Tags: email, exchange

I have noticed than in many popular email services such as GMail and Exchange, the email address of the user also contains the name of the sender.

For example jsmith@company.com will show up as `John Smith <jsmith@company.com>`.

Is there a way to determine the user name associated with an account by querying the server for that information? (in this case MS Exchange).

I want to create a script that automatically extracts the first and last name from their address to do personalize outgoing emails.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you only have mails in the form `username@example.com` and want to (magically) get their full name, even if it's not supplied through the mail? Or does the mail's sender actually appear as `John Doe <username@example.com`? In what form do you have the mails (or access to them, respectively)? What's your operating system?

Comment: @slhck: The only available data is the email address itself. The intended service is MS Exchange which should supply a full name every time. Access would be within the same domain. Unix Platform

Comment: I don't think this is doable at all. If you had the full mail, including its header where the `From:` field designates the e-mail address and the sender's full name, that'd be no problem to extract, but just with the e-mail address alone…

Comment: your probably right, I was just holding out hope that there was some way of querying an Exchange or IMAP server for this information

Comment: That, I don't know. With Gmail it won't be possible, but you might have a change with an Exchange server you can query. But that's out of my knowledge, sorry :)

Comment: If you have a full exchange / active directory deployment (such as inside a company), and you know the emails are internal `<username>@domain`, then you can perform an LDAP query against the domain controller to pull first and last name based on username. This will not work for users outside of the domain, though.

Comment: I agree that it’s almost certainly impossible.  It might have been possible 20 years ago, but, as spam and phishing have increased, there has been a trend for mail servers/services to give out less and less information on their subscribers; e.g., not even confirming whether an email address is valid/active.

Comment: Normally your email client will notice the "friendly name" in incoming emails and store these for later use. As a general rule, you can't iterate through directories, for both SPAM and security (keep logins private when you can) reasons.

Comment: @DarthAndroid, in this case yes it would be internal with a full LDAP and AD deployment. This would be for internal use.

Comment: @BrandonKreisel [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/324585/222364) should get you headed in the right direction, though work would be required to get it into a runnable script. Perhaps reword your question to "Given an internal email address, how can I query Active Directory for that user's full name and print it out on the command line?"